# WooCommerce get custom field from attributte

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is it possible to get custom field from product attribute?
And can be connected by variation or product id?
I tried this one:

```
       function color_in_loop(){
        global $product;

        //Getting product attributes
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color', array( 'fields' =>  'all' ) );
        
        foreach ( $values as $term ) {
            $icon = get_term_meta('product_attribute_color', 'pa_color_'.$term->term_id);
            echo $icon['url'];
        }
    }
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'color_in_loop');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get_term_meta is wrong, and there is no need to use

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
```

You can achieve what you are looking for simply with the `get_the_terms` method since you know the specific attribute you need the icon for.

```
function color_in_loop(){
    global $product;

    //Getting product attributes
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $colors = get_the_terms($product_id, 'pa_color');
    
    foreach ( $colors as $color ) {
        $icon = get_term_meta($color->term_id,'product_attribute_color',true);
        echo $icon['url'];
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'color_in_loop');
```

It is not tested but it should work